# Can you trigger an Azure AD token expiry for a specific App and User?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

So I've got an application that's a mobile client and an API back-end - using Azure AD for authentication.  I'm using Azures "Enterprise Application" role functionality so that I can add roles to specific users that I'm allowing to login to the app.

The kind of setup I'm talking about is similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

By adding these roles I'm essentially adding claims into the users token (the role claim).  That token is then saved for however long - say an hour - and used with every request they send the API.

**The problem:** If a user is in the "Basic" role, and I change his role so he's in the "Admin" role the users claims wont be updated because he retrieved his token before I made the role change.  The user will therefore have the same "Basic" level of access until he logs out and back in again (to refresh the claims).

**So the question is this:**  Is there a way I can force the mobile client to trigger a token refresh for a user when I change the users role in the Enterprise App?  I'm thinking it would be great to trigger a token expiry in the back-end somehow, but not sure if it's possible.

From what I understand about authentication and authorisation I don't believe it's possible.  If that's true it really highlights the downsides of storing roles (which are essentially like permissions) in a claim.  Asking the question because I've been wrong before many many many times....

Comment: I did not find a way to invalidate the access token only. For web application, you can use "Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken" to invalidate the refresh tokens issued to applications for a user. The cmdlet also invalidates tokens issued to session cookies in a browser for the user. For more details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: User will be asked to login again, and new token will be acquired.